# Chat event to liven up chat?

Tags: discussion, chat

Our chat room is pretty empty, how about a chat event of some sort to get people interested, maybe pick up a couple regulars?

Answer (score 3):

For a getting-to-know-you sort of event I was thinking maybe an event to gab about our current cars/projects. Something simple probably everyone on the site could be involved with.

Answer (score 2):

Chat meet-ups are a great idea.  My personal participation will be driven by schedule, though: I have zero access to chat while I'm at work.  That shouldn't drive the schedule, it's just an issue that plenty of people will deal with.

Maybe the first milestone would be to regularly get a core group of five-ten folks who regularly hit chat for a bit of sh*t-shooting.